# Add Hyperlink to Cell in Excel 2007 Using Open XML SDK 2.0

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

I can't seem to find any documentation or code samples on how to add a hyperlink to a cell in Excel 2007 using the Open XML SDK 2.0.  I am using the following code, but is there a step I am missing?

```
WorksheetPart workSheetPart = ExcelUtilities.GetWorkSheetPart(mWorkBookPart, "Program");

workSheetPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute), true);

workSheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

mWorkBookPart.Workbook.Save();
```

Then when I try and open the Excel document it says the file is corrupted because the Relationship Id for the hyperlink cannot be found.  How do you setup or create that Relationship Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add a hyperlink to a cell using `System.IO.Packaging` code:

```
private void HyperlinkCreate(PackagePart part, XmlNamespaceManager nsm, XmlNode _cellElement, string CellAddress)
{
        Uri _hyperlink = new Uri("http://www.yahoo.com");
        XmlNode linkParent = _cellElement.OwnerDocument.SelectSingleNode("//d:hyperlinks", nsm);
        if (linkParent == null)
        {
            // create the hyperlinks node
            linkParent = _cellElement.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("hyperlinks", @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main");
            XmlNode prevNode = _cellElement.OwnerDocument.SelectSingleNode("//d:conditionalFormatting", nsm);
            if (prevNode == null)
            {
                prevNode = _cellElement.OwnerDocument.SelectSingleNode("//d:mergeCells", nsm);
                if (prevNode == null)
                {
                    prevNode = _cellElement.OwnerDocument.SelectSingleNode("//d:sheetData", nsm);
                }
            }
            _cellElement.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(linkParent, prevNode);
        }
        string searchString = string.Format("./d:hyperlink[@ref = '{0}']", CellAddress);
        XmlElement linkNode = (XmlElement)linkParent.SelectSingleNode(searchString, nsm);
        XmlAttribute attr;
        if (linkNode == null)
        {
            linkNode = _cellElement.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("hyperlink", @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main");
            // now add cell address attribute
            linkNode.SetAttribute("ref", CellAddress);
            linkParent.AppendChild(linkNode);
        }

        attr = (XmlAttribute)linkNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id", @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
        if (attr == null)
        {
            attr = _cellElement.OwnerDocument.CreateAttribute("r", "id", @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            linkNode.Attributes.Append(attr);
        }                     

        PackageRelationship relationship = null;
        string relID = attr.Value;
        if (relID == "")
            relationship = part.CreateRelationship(_hyperlink, TargetMode.External, @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink");
        else
        {
            relationship = part.GetRelationship(relID);
            if (relationship.TargetUri != _hyperlink)
                relationship = part.CreateRelationship(_hyperlink, TargetMode.External, @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink");
        }
        attr.Value = relationship.Id;
}
```

I then translated this code using the Open XML SDK 2.0 and it doesn't work.  It seems the `AddHyperlinkRelationship` method doesn't actually add the relationship to the **.rels** file.  I'm not sure why, but it sure seems like a bug to me.

```
private void HyperlinkCreate(PackagePart part, XmlNamespaceManager nsm, XmlNode _cellElement, string CellAddress)
    {

WorksheetPart workSheetPart = ExcelUtilities.GetWorkSheetPart(mWorkBookPart, "Program");
            Uri hyperlinkUri = new Uri("http://www.yahoo.com", UriKind.Absolute);

            Hyperlinks hyperlinks = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Hyperlinks>().FirstOrDefault();

            // Check to see if the <x:hyperlinks> element exists; if not figure out 
            // where to insert it depending on which elements are present in the Worksheet
            if (hyperlinks == null)
            {
                // Create the hyperlinks node
                hyperlinks = new Hyperlinks();

                OpenXmlCompositeElement prevElement = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<ConditionalFormatting>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (prevElement == null)
                {
                    prevElement = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<MergeCells>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (prevElement == null)
                    {
                        // No FirstOrDefault needed since a Worksheet requires SheetData or the excel doc will be corrupt
                        prevElement = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<SheetData>().First();
                    }
                }
                workSheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(hyperlinks, prevElement);
            }
            Hyperlink hyperlink = hyperlinks.Descendants<Hyperlink>().Where(r => r.Reference.Equals(CellAddress)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (hyperlink == null)
            {
                hyperlink = new Hyperlink() { Reference = CellAddress, Id = string.Empty };

            }

            HyperlinkRelationship hyperlinkRelationship = null;
            string relId = hyperlink.Id;
            if (relId.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                hyperlinkRelationship = workSheetPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(hyperlinkUri, true);
            }
            else
            {
                hyperlinkRelationship = workSheetPart.GetReferenceRelationship(relId) as HyperlinkRelationship;
                if (!hyperlinkRelationship.Uri.Equals(hyperlinkUri))
                {
                    hyperlinkRelationship = workSheetPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(hyperlinkUri, true);
                }
            }
            hyperlink.Id = hyperlinkRelationship.Id;
            hyperlinks.AppendChild<Hyperlink>(hyperlink);
            workSheetPart.Worksheet.Save();     
        }
```

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility, (which I used), is to use the [HYPERLINK](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hyperlink-HP005209116.aspx) formula for Excel.  I needed to create individual hyperlinks in each cell, yet the cells had to display different text, (I had to display tracking numbers in the cells yet have a hyperlink for each tracking number to the carrier's site and had to handle multiple carriers).

Once I instantiated an individual cell, the formula was applied in this manner to each cell (there are undoubtedly numerous way):

```
// ...
Cell cell1 = new Cell(){ CellReference = "A1", StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U, DataType = CellValues.InlineString };
CellValue cellValue1 = new CellValue();

CellFormula cellFormula1 = new CellFormula() { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
cellFormula1.Text = @"HYPERLINK(""http://www.theclash.com"", ""Radio Clash"")";
cellValue1.Text = "Radio Clash";
cell1.Append(cellFormula1);
cell1.Append(cellValue1);
// append cell, etc.
```

In this way, I was able to create individual hyperlinks and text for each cell.  By the way, the links will appear with the default font color unless you reference a style with blue font.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice option.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should be adding it to an object that accepts hyperlinks, such as a cell, instead of the worksheet. Something like this should work for you:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

namespace GeneratedCode
{
    public class GeneratedClass
    {
        // Creates an Worksheet instance and adds its children.
        public Worksheet GenerateWorksheet()
        {
            Worksheet worksheet1 = new Worksheet(){ MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes(){ Ignorable = "x14ac" }  };
            worksheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            worksheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            worksheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14ac", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac");
            SheetDimension sheetDimension1 = new SheetDimension(){ Reference = "A1" };

            SheetViews sheetViews1 = new SheetViews();
            SheetView sheetView1 = new SheetView(){ TabSelected = true, WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U };

            sheetViews1.Append(sheetView1);
            SheetFormatProperties sheetFormatProperties1 = new SheetFormatProperties(){ DefaultRowHeight = 14.4D, DyDescent = 0.3D };

            SheetData sheetData1 = new SheetData();

            Row row1 = new Row(){ RowIndex = (UInt32Value)1U, Spans = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "1:1" }, DyDescent = 0.3D };

            Cell cell1 = new Cell(){ CellReference = "A1", StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U, DataType = CellValues.SharedString };
            CellValue cellValue1 = new CellValue();
            cellValue1.Text = "0";

            cell1.Append(cellValue1);

            row1.Append(cell1);

            sheetData1.Append(row1);

            Hyperlinks hyperlinks1 = new Hyperlinks();
            Hyperlink hyperlink1 = new Hyperlink(){ Reference = "A1", Id = "rId1" };

            hyperlinks1.Append(hyperlink1);
            PageMargins pageMargins1 = new PageMargins(){ Left = 0.7D, Right = 0.7D, Top = 0.75D, Bottom = 0.75D, Header = 0.3D, Footer = 0.3D };

            worksheet1.Append(sheetDimension1);
            worksheet1.Append(sheetViews1);
            worksheet1.Append(sheetFormatProperties1);
            worksheet1.Append(sheetData1);
            worksheet1.Append(hyperlinks1);
            worksheet1.Append(pageMargins1);
            return worksheet1;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to access a Cell object directly from a Worksheet. I'm using the open xml sdk 2.0 and as far as I can tell there is no .Hyperlink property on the Cell object

Comment: apologies, some things have changed with the RTM of 2.0. See above for reflected example.

Comment: yeah that code will work, but I already have an existing sheet and want to add a hyperlink to a cell that already exists.

Comment: Just change the initializatio of `worksheet1` to be your worksheet and change the other initiliazation items like creating new cells. Set the references to what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the HyperLink formular, but the links aren't blue by default, this is why the styleIndex is set.

```
 private Cell BuildHyperlinkCell(string url) =>
    new Cell
    {
      DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String),
      CellFormula = new CellFormula($"HyperLink(\"{url}\")"),
      StyleIndex = 4u
    };
```

Adding the styling to the workbook:
http://www.dispatchertimer.com/tutorial/how-to-create-an-excel-file-in-net-using-openxml-part-3-add-stylesheet-to-the-spreadsheet/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a hyperlink with this function

```
/// <summary>
/// Add Hyperlink to Excel Worksheet
/// </summary>
/// <param name="worksheetDoc">Worksheet</param>
/// <param name="colName">Column name (A, B, C..)</param>
/// <param name="rowIndex">Row index (start from 1)</param>
/// <param name="link">a URI</param>  
public static void AddHyperlik(WorksheetPart worksheetDoc, string colName, int rowIndex,System.Uri link)
{
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Hyperlinks ls1 = worksheetDoc.Worksheet.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Hyperlinks>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (ls1 == null)
    {
        ls1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Hyperlinks();
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PageMargins pm = worksheetDoc.Worksheet.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PageMargins>().First();
        worksheetDoc.Worksheet.InsertBefore(ls1, pm);
    }
    int idIdx = 1;
    var list1 = ls1.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Hyperlink>().ToList().Select(x => x.Id.Value);
    if (list1.Count() > 0 && list1.Where(y => y.Contains("IdLink")).Any())
    {
        idIdx = 1 + list1.Where(y => y.Contains("IdLink")).Select(x => int.Parse(x.Replace("IdLink", ""))).Max();
    }
    string id = "IdLink" + idIdx.ToString();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Hyperlink l1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Hyperlink() { Reference = (colName + rowIndex), Id = id };
    ls1.Append(l1);
    worksheetDoc.Worksheet.Save();
    worksheetDoc.AddHyperlinkRelationship(link, true, id);
}
```